# Adding build tools to a Kaniko image for Gitlab-CI

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, kaniko

Given a monorepo of ~35 services using a Gitlab-CI with k8s runners.
The images are built using Kaniko, utilizing `<job>.extends` of a prototype template, and life is great.

However, lately, we wanted to save a key on consul and change a gitlab-ci env-var after a successful build - which requires `curl`, and preferably `jq`.

I've been trying to create the following image to serve as image for image-building jobs:

```bash
FROM gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug

RUN mkdir -p /workspace \
  && wget -qO /workspace/curl https://github.com/moparisthebest/static-curl/releases/download/v7.86.0/curl-amd64 \
  && chmod +x /workspace/curl \
  && wget -qO /workspace/jq https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.6/jq-linux64 \
  && chmod +x /workspace/jq

ENV PATH "$PATH:/workspace"
```

The build of which appears to succeed.

However - de-facto, when used in a pipeline job, given the following script:

```
.build-with-kaniko:
  script:
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker;
      echo "{\"auths\":{\"${CI_REGISTRY}\":{\"auth\":..... > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - which jq || log no jq;
      which curl || log no curl;
    - >- 
      /kaniko/executor
      --context $PROJECT_PATH
      --dockerfile $DOCKERFILE
      --destination ${CI_REGISTRY}/${DOCKER_REPO}:${TAG}
    - which jq || log no jq;
      which curl || log no curl;
```

Before running the `executor` - the `curl` and `jq` are found.

But after running the `executor` - they are gone!! `<tam-tam-taaaaaaAAAMM!!!> :o`

I tried placing them in few different folders: `/busibox`, `/kaniko`, `/workspace` or even a custom dir `/misc`-  and could not get it to work...

I thought maybe it packs them to the target image - but no, they are not there.

I also noted that after building with `--no-push` they are still there
(but then I do not get my image on the registry...).

What is going on? is there a post-push cleanup mechanism I should instruct to leave these two files?

Help?
What must I do to help kaniko understand I need these two utilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMG. :facepalm:

I knew I'll find the answer only after I post the question...  :shrug:

#### Here's what worked:

Declare it as a new volume:

```bash
FROM gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug

RUN mkdir -p /misc \
  && wget -qO /misc/curl https://github.com/moparisthebest/static-curl/releases/download/v7.86.0/curl-amd64 \
  && chmod +x /misc/curl \
  && wget -qO /misc/jq https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.6/jq-linux64 \
  && chmod +x /misc/jq

VOLUME /misc

ENV PATH "$PATH:/misc"
```

I got the clue from the current Dockerfile of the [kaniko:debug image](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/blob/8710ce3311be79a331a325d57d13a1b9df6aa5a6/deploy/Dockerfile_debug#L61) itself (at the time of this writing).

The image is recommended to be used as the base image for gitlab-ci jobs that use kaniko - and it includes `/busybox`.

I still don't understand why putting the tools in `/busybox` dir did not work, but I got a working solution now, and no time to dig deeper :sad: :shrug:

Answer (score 1):

You saved my day, your method works well, curl is correctly installed!

But when I tried to use `curl` (v7.88.1) I got this error:

> curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile:
> /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CApath: /kaniko/ssl/certs

I fixed this error by copying the generated certificate to default location of installed certificates `/etc/ssl/certs`.

```
RUN mkdir -p /etc/ssl/certs \
  && cp /kaniko/ssl/certs/* /etc/ssl/certs
```